# reduce: sum of lengths doesn't produce expected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, reduce

I am trying to access the key 'children' inside of these nested arrays listed below. I want a total count of how many children there are. I am rather new to coding and I've been trying some things out but have not been able to figure the problem. any help?

also, I want to use the reduce method to accomplish this task thanks!

```
const characters = [
  {
    name: 'Eddard',
    spouse: 'Catelyn',
    children: ['Robb', 'Sansa', 'Arya', 'Bran', 'Rickon'],
    house: 'Stark',
  },
  {
    name: 'Jon',
    spouse: 'Lysa',
    children: ['Robin'],
    house: 'Arryn',
  },
  {
    name: 'Cersei',
    spouse: 'Robert',
    children: ['Joffrey', 'Myrcella', 'Tommen'],
    house: 'Lannister',
  },
  {
    name: 'Daenarys',
    spouse: 'Khal Drogo',
    children: ['Drogon', 'Rhaegal', 'Viserion'],
    house: 'Targaryen',
  },
  {
    name: 'Mace',
    spouse: 'Alerie',
    children: ['Margaery', 'Loras'],
    house: 'Tyrell',
  },
  {
    name: 'Sansa',
    spouse: 'Tyrion',
    house: 'Stark',
  },
  {
    name: 'Jon',
    spouse: null,
    house: 'Snow',
  },
];

const countNumberOfChildren = (arr) => {
  const selectChildren = arr.reduce((acc, c)=>{
   console.log('this is c', c)
   console.log('this is acc', acc)
   acc + c.children.length()
   console.log('this is acc2', acc)

  return acc
  }, 0)
  console.log(selectChildren) 
};

countNumberOfChildren(characters)
```

Comment: `acc += c.children.length;` — `.length` is not a function, and you have to use `+=` to make the accumulator change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `acc + c.children.length()` does not change the `acc` variable and that `.length` is not a function, it is a property. Also, so elements might not have a `.children` property.

You can condense that entire `.reduce()` call into one line and use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [null coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) to handle elements that don't have a `.children` array like this:

```js
const characters=[{name:'Eddard',spouse:'Catelyn',children:['Robb','Sansa','Arya','Bran','Rickon'],house:'Stark'},{name:'Jon',spouse:'Lysa',children:['Robin'],house:'Arryn'},{name:'Cersei',spouse:'Robert',children:['Joffrey','Myrcella','Tommen'],house:'Lannister'},{name:'Daenarys',spouse:'Khal Drogo',children:['Drogon','Rhaegal','Viserion'],house:'Targaryen'},{name:'Mace',spouse:'Alerie',children:['Margaery','Loras'],house:'Tyrell'},{name:'Sansa',spouse:'Tyrion',house:'Stark'},{name:'Jon',spouse:null,house:'Snow'}];


const numChildren = characters.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + (curr.children?.length ?? 0), 0);
console.log(numChildren);
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. I can see where my mistakes were. To be honest I haven't gotten to the null  coalescing operator yet so I didn't even know that existed. One follow up question I have is in this block of code here, (curr.children?.length ?? 0), 0) what is the single '?' accomplishing or better yet what is that  called so I can read into how it works. I went ahead and red the MDN for the ?? operator  so thanks for that!

Comment: @Avreeland Always happy to help! That `?.` operator is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). If my answer solved your question, then you can mark it as correct (the checkmark). This would help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: @Avreeland Why did you unaccept this answer? Is there an issue I should fix?

Comment: no sir! that was a mistake, I went back and reaccepted, thanks for checking and sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your countNumberOfChildren function to

```
const countNumberOfChildren = (arr) => {
  const selectChildren = arr.reduce((acc, c) =>  acc + (c.children ? c.children.length : 0), 0);
  return selectChildren;    
};
```

Here, we are first checking whether a property named 'children' exists in the current element (c) or not. If it exist then add its length to acc else add 0.